How to Resolve Linting Errors Related to Promise Handling in TypeScript with ESLint?
I'm currently working on a Node.js application using TypeScript and Prisma. While trying to implement a database connection and server startup logic, I'm encountering linting errors related to promise handling, specifically with the ESLint rule @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises and @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import app from './app';
import config from './config/config';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const client = new PrismaClient();

const startServer = async () => {
    try {
        await client.$connect();
        console.log('Connection to the database is established successfully.');

        app.listen(config.PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server is listening on localhost:${config.PORT}`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to start the server due to database connection issues:', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

startServer();

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    console.error('Uncaught Exception:', err);
    process.exit(1);
});

// Here is the problem
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    console.error('Unhandled Rejection:', err);
    process.exit(1);
});

Linting Error Output:
C:\path\to\your\file.ts
  42:34  error  Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected  @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises

I added async to the unhandledRejection handler to await promises, but I'm still facing linting issues.
I reviewed the ESLint rules, but I'm unsure how to correctly handle promises in this context.
How can I resolve these linting errors while ensuring proper promise handling in my TypeScript application? Any guidance on best practices for handling unhandled promise rejections in Node.js would be greatly appreciated!

You already handled promises, the problem is solely eslint. What location is  42:34? Did you check that there's linter error in the simplified code? I don't see the possibility for no-misused-promises here. As for no-floating-promises, it would be startServer().catch(console.error) if you expect errors, and startServer().catch(() => {}) if you don't. And it's cleaner with no questions asked if you add ignore comment to the line and leave code as is

Have you read the documentation on the two errors? Those pages describe what triggers them and what to do instead pretty well already. I don't think having someone copy and paste what is said there in an answer here does anyone any good. If you don't get something from there, I'm sure someone would be happy to explain, given a specific example...

"I added async to the unhandledRejection handler to await promises" - huh? Please post that code. Your current unhandledRejection handler neither is marked as async nor does it await any promises.
